# system verilog HDL - 4bit input logical calculator

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, quartus, digital

I'm trying to design a logical calculator that can plus, multiply, division, ...
but I stuck at 1 part when I try to run it on the DE 10 board it doesn't act as the logic I though
My logic is that when count = 0, the operand A will be at HEX 4,5 and count = 1 DoOpt will be at 2, and count = 2 operand B will display at HEX 1,0, then count will be reset. However when I run it only shows operand B only. can you figure for me what is wrong with my code?

```
module group_project (
    input logic clk, Set, AC,
    input logic [3:0] Operand,
    input logic [2:0] DoOp,
    output logic [6:0] Seg5, Seg4, Seg3, Seg2, Seg1, Seg0
);
    logic [1:0] count;
    always_ff@(posedge clk) begin
        if(!AC) begin
            Seg5 = 7'b000_1000;
            Seg4 = 7'b000_0110;
            Seg3 = 7'b000_1000;
            Seg2 = 7'b100_0000;
            Seg1 = 7'b001_0001;
            Seg0 = 7'b011_1111;
            count <= 2'b00;
        end
        if(!Set && count == 2'b00) begin
        count <= count + 1;
            Seg3 = 7'b111_1111;
            Seg2 = 7'b111_1111;
            Seg1 = 7'b111_1111;
            Seg0 = 7'b111_1111;

            if(Operand < 4'b1010) begin
                Seg5 = 7'b100_0000;
                case (Operand)
                    4'b0000: Seg4 = 7'b100_0000;
                    4'b0001: Seg4 = 7'b111_1001;
                    4'b0010: Seg4 = 7'b010_0100;
                    4'b0011: Seg4 = 7'b011_0000;
                    4'b0100: Seg4 = 7'b001_1001;
                    4'b0101: Seg4 = 7'b001_0010;
                    4'b0110: Seg4 = 7'b000_0010;
                    4'b0111: Seg4 = 7'b111_1000;
                    4'b1000: Seg4 = 7'b000_0000;
                    4'b1001: Seg4 = 7'b001_0000;
                endcase
            end
            else begin
                Seg5 = 7'b111_1001;
                case (Operand)
                    4'b1010: Seg4 = 7'b100_0000;
                    4'b1011: Seg4 = 7'b111_1001;
                    4'b1100: Seg4 = 7'b010_0100;
                    4'b1101: Seg4 = 7'b011_0000;
                    4'b1110: Seg4 = 7'b001_1001;
                    4'b1111: Seg4 = 7'b001_0010;
                endcase
            end
        end

        
         if(!Set && count == 2'b01) begin   
         count <= count + 1;
            Seg5 = 7'b111_1111;
            Seg4 = 7'b111_1111;
            Seg3 = 7'b111_1111;
            Seg1 = 7'b111_1111;
            Seg0 = 7'b111_1111;

            
            case(DoOp)
                3'b001: Seg2 = 7'b111_1001;
                3'b010: Seg2 = 7'b010_0100;
                3'b011: Seg2 = 7'b011_0000;
                3'b100: Seg2 = 7'b001_1001;
                3'b101: Seg2 = 7'b001_0010;
            endcase 
        end

        

        
        /*else if(!Set && count == 2'b10) begin
            Seg5 = 7'b111_1111;
            Seg4 = 7'b111_1111;
            Seg3 = 7'b111_1111;
            Seg2 = 7'b111_1111;
            count <= count;
            if(Operand < 4'b1010) begin
                Seg1 = 7'b100_0000;
                case (Operand)
                4'b0000: Seg0 = 7'b100_0000;
                4'b0001: Seg0 = 7'b111_1001;
                4'b0010: Seg0 = 7'b010_0100;
                4'b0011: Seg0 = 7'b011_0000;
                4'b0100: Seg0 = 7'b001_1001;
                4'b0101: Seg0 = 7'b001_0010;
                4'b0110: Seg0 = 7'b000_0010;
                4'b0111: Seg0 = 7'b111_1000;
                4'b1000: Seg0 = 7'b000_0000;
                4'b1001: Seg0 = 7'b001_0000;
                endcase
            end
            else begin
                Seg1 = 7'b111_1001;
                case (Operand)
                4'b1010: Seg0 = 7'b100_0000;
                4'b1011: Seg0 = 7'b111_1001;
                4'b1100: Seg0 = 7'b010_0100;
                4'b1101: Seg0 = 7'b011_0000;
                4'b1110: Seg0 = 7'b001_1001;
                4'b1111: Seg0 = 7'b001_0010;
                endcase
            end
        end
    end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

There's something to do with `AC` and `Set`.

If `AC` is used as initial reset only, and after that `Set` is constant low, then `count` will at last stay at 2. It only lasts 1 `clk` cycle for `count` = 0 and 1. So as long as `clk` is fast enough, you'll be unable to notice `count` = 0 and 1, and only see `count` = 2 state.

Perhaps you need to deassert `AC` periodically, and control `Set` to see the transition of each `count` state.

Comment: can you show me a little example of it? I can't think through the logic of that

Comment: @Hieu Could you post your testbench? Or describe the timing of AC and Set. Because these 2 control signals are important, and are driven outside your module.